# Migrate from Simple Fields to Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: mysql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to migrate my WordPress site from the Simple Fields plugin to the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

I've created all the ACF components now I just need to populate them with the data from the SF database.

The table that stores the data is `wp_postmeta` and the columns are `meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, and `meta_value`.

`meta_id` is the unique ID for each row so this column doesn't really help me much, so `post_id` is the column that matters.

I need to move data from `meta_value` where `meta_key` equals `_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_3_fieldID_7_numInSet_0`to `meta_value` where `meta_key` equals `hero_description`, `hero_description` is empty, and the `post_id` is identical.

I'm going to have to repeat this process for all the SF `meta_key` that have a corresponding `ACF` `meta_key`.

I know very very little mySQL so I don't know where to start.

Could anyone help me with the logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend gave me this query that works like a charm. Here it is for anyone else he needs to migrate from Simple Fields to Advanced Custom Fields

```
SET @key_from = " _simple_fields_fieldGroupID_3_fieldID_0_numInSet_0";
SET @key_to = "hero_title";

UPDATE wp_postmeta a,
(
   SELECT
   meta_id,post_id,meta_key,meta_value
   FROM wp_postmeta
   WHERE meta_key = @key_from
   AND meta_value <> ''
)
b SET a.meta_value = b.meta_value
WHERE a.meta_key = @key_to
and a.meta_value = ''
and a.post_id = b.post_id
```

Basically all you have to do is find out what SF `meta_key` corresponds to what ACF `meta_key` and set `@key_from` and `@key_to` accordingly.